# Mixing DEFINEs with Literal Strings in C++

Tags: c++

I've created a #define which points to a particular directory. I would then like to use this definition in combination with a string literal:

```
#define PATH_RESOURCES "/path/to/resources/"
std::ifstream datafile(PATH_RESOURCES + "textures.dat");
```

However, the compiler complains about adding char types using the + operator:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [11]’ and ‘const char [13]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

So how can I combine a #define with a string literal? Or, is there a better way of doing this altogether? I imagine using a const variable would be an alternative, but this would mean having to pass around yet another parameter which I'd rather prefer to keep as a global definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two string literals by writing them one after the other with no `+` plus between them:

```
std::ifstream datafile(PATH_RESOURCES "textures.dat");
```

The fact that one of the string literals happens to be defined through the preprocessor does not change much: you can do it like this as well:

```
std::ifstream datafile(PATH_"/path/to/resources/" "textures.dat");
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/IejqjH).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I wasn't aware that string literals could be combined like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 std::ifstream datafile(PATH_RESOURCES "textures.dat");
```

Two string literals adjacent concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::ifstream datafile(PATH_RESOURCES "textures.data");`

Note the lack of the + operator.

You could also do

`std::ifstream datafile(std::string(PATH_RESOURCES) + std::string("textures.data"));` if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a std::string, assign your #define string to it and add the second literal. Afterwards use the string.

```
std::string str(PATH_RESOURCES);
str = str + "textures.dat";
std::ifstream datafile(str);
```